# Foreign key not saving with OneToMany relationship in Doctrine/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Here are my two entity classes:

```
<?php

namespace IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 */
class Article
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $heading;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Version
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $created = null;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article", cascade="persist")
     */
    private $comments;



    // non persisted

    protected $username;

    protected $user_id;


    public function setUsername($username) {

        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUserId($id) {



        $this->user_id = $id;
    }
    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
    // end non persisted


    // can this be hooked into event?  i.e. JMSSerialiser?
    public function beforeSerialisation() {

        $this->setUserid($this->user->getId());
        $this->setUsername($this->user->getUsername());
        $this->setUser(null);
    }





    public function __construct() {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set heading
     *
     * @param string $heading
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setHeading($heading)
    {
        $this->heading = $heading;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get heading
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getHeading()
    {
        return $this->heading;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setUser(\IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    { 
        return $this->user;
    }



    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }


    /**
     * Get comments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Add comments
     *
     * @param \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments
     * @return Article
     */
    public function addComment(\IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments)
    {
        $this->comments[] = $comments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove comments
     *
     * @param \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments
     */
    public function removeComment(\IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments)
    {
        $this->comments->removeElement($comments);
    }
}
```

```
namespace IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class Comment
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Version
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $created = null;


     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;



    public function __construct() {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }



    // non persisted
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="digit")
     */
    protected $article_id;

    public function setArticleId($id) {
        $this->article_id = $id;
    }
    public function getArticleId() {
        return $this->article_id;
    }
    // end non persisted



    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Article $article
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setArticle(\IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Article $article = null)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Article 
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }
}
```

Later in the code I am binding data to a form for comment, retrieving the article by id and calling $article->addComment($comment) and then calling:

```
$this->entityManager->persist($article);
$this->entityManager->persist($comment);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

The comment is saving but doesn't contain the reference/foreign key to article.

Answer (score 0):

You call `addComment` on the Article but `setArticle` is never called on your Comment. You can modify the setter `addComment` in order to make it call `setArticle` :

```
/**
 * Add comments
 *
 * @param \IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments
 * @return Article
 */
public function addComment(\IW\Bundle\ArticlesBundle\Entity\Comment $comments)
{
    $this->comments[] = $comments;
    $comments->setArticle($this);

    return $this;
}
```